# What is the difference between "__send__" and "instance_variable_get / instance_variable_set" methods?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, instance-variables

All is stated in the question.
Both of these methods can access (read/write) instance variables by using their code name :

```
__send__


instance_variable_set
instance_variable_get
```

Could someone explain it by examples ?

Metaprogramming is sometimes melting our brain when we explore it with abstraction.

=== EDIT ===

Ok I make a resume of the answers as an example for later use if my brain is melting again.

**Class declaration** :

```
class Person

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
  end

  def full_name
    @first_name + ' ' + @last_name
  end

end
```

**Initialization** :

```
actor = Person.new('Donald', "Duck")
=> #<Person:0xa245554 @first_name="Donald", @last_name="Duck">
```

**usage of send** (read) :

```
actor.send('first_name')
=> "Donald"

actor.send(:first_name)
=> "Donald"

actor.send("last_name")
=> "Duck"

actor.send(:last_name)
=> "Duck"

actor.send('full_name')
=> "Donald Duck"

actor.send(:full_name)
=> "Donald Duck"
```

**usage of instance_variable_get** (read)

```
actor.instance_variable_get('@first_name')
=> "Donald"

actor.instance_variable_get(:@first_name)
=> "Donald"

actor.instance_variable_get('@last_name')
=> "Duck"

actor.instance_variable_get(:@last_name)
=> "Duck"
```

**usage of send** (write) :

```
actor.send('first_name=', 'Daisy')

actor.send('full_name')
=> "Daisy Duck"

actor.send(:first_name=, "Fifi")

actor.send("full_name")
=> "Fifi Duck"
```

**usage of instance_variable_set** (write)

```
actor.instance_variable_set('@first_name', 'Pluto')
actor.send("full_name")
=> "Pluto Duck"

actor.instance_variable_set(:@last_name, 'Dog')
actor.send(:full_name)
=> "Pluto Dog"
```

**INCORRECT usage of instance_variable_get** (read)

```
actor.instance_variable_get('full_name')
#NameError: `full_name' is not allowed as an instance variable name

actor.instance_variable_get('last_name')
#NameError: `last_name' is not allowed as an instance variable name
```

I was geting confuse with Rails ActiveRecord and its Associations.

Thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__send__` methods invokes method which are defined in your class, if the method is not defined then you cannot use `send` method, but `instance_variable_get` and `set` methods changes the value of the instance variable without the need for any encapsulating methods (like getters or setters).

`__send__` is used if you want to invoke a method identified by the symbol and passing any argument if needed.

e.g.

```
class Test
  def sayHello(*args)
    "Hello " + args.join(' ')
  end
end
k = Test.new
k.send :sayHello, "readers"   #=> "Hello readers"
```

`instance_variable_get` Returns the value of the given instance variable, or nil if the instance variable is not set. Use this method without the need for encapsulation

e.g

```
class Test
  def initialize(p1)
    @a = p1
  end
end
test = Test.new('animal')
test.instance_variable_get(:@a)    #=> "animal"
```

`instance_variable_set` used to set the value for an instance variable without the need for encapsulating methods.
e.g

```
class Test
  def initialize(p1)
    @a = p1
  end
end
test = Test.new('animal')
test.instance_variable_set(:@a, 'animal')
```

Answer (score 2):

`__send__` allows you to *call a method* by name/symbol,
`instance_variable_*` allows you to set/get *instance variables*.

Comment: I can use both "__send__" and "instance_variable_get" to read the attribut of an object. Same remark apply to "instance_variable_set" to write an object attribut. It works.

Comment: An attribute declared with `attr_accessor :my_thing` is a combination of an instance variable `@my_thing`, a reader method `my_thing`, and a writer method `my_thing=`. You can use `__send__` to invoke either the reader or writer method by name, or you can use `instance_variable_get` or `instance_variable_set` to read or write the instance variable `@my_thing` directly and bypass the reader and writer methods `my_thing` and `my_thing=`. In **some** cases they will both work out the same way; but in **other** cases they will not.